# Combining columns with no common element (pivot) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to find the best way to display some data.

My dataset looks like this:

```
Form  var1_Day  var1_WTD  var1_30Day  var2_Day  var2_WTD  var2_30Day ...
NA    null      null      null        77        448       2581
A1    166       791       4842        null      null      null
A2    304       1312      8365        null      null      null
A3    29        113       656         null      null      null
```

I am trying to figure out how I would go about displaying the data like this:

```
Var   Form  Day   WTD   30Day
var1  NA    null  null  null
var1  A1    166   791   4842
var1  A2    304   1312  8365
var1  A3    29    113   656
var2  NA    77    448   2581
var2  A1    null  null  null
var2  A2    null  null  null
var2  A3    null  null  null
...
```

I believe I will have to use a pivot table but am not sure where to start.

Thank You,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want `UNPIVOT`

Like so...

```
select SUBSTRING(t,1,4) as Var, form, day, wtd, 30day 
from yourtable
unpivot ([day] for d in (var1_day,var2_day)) td
unpivot ([wtd] for w in (var1_wtd,var2_wtd)) tw
unpivot ([30day] for t in (var1_30day,var2_30day)) tt
where SUBSTRING(d,1,4) = SUBSTRING(w,1,4)
and  SUBSTRING(d,1,4) = SUBSTRING(t,1,4)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I put it in a sql-fiddle to test it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/caa7a/4

Comment: If you have more than 9 types of var, you'll need to tweak the filters at the end - they assume it goes from var1 - var9

Answer (score 2):

While you can do this via a static pivot like the other answer, if you have a lot of columns to transform you can use a dynamic pivot:

```
DECLARE @colsUnPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsUnPivotNull as NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('test') and
               C.name like 'var%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @colsUnPivotNull = stuff((select ', IsNull('+ quotename(C.name) +', 0)' + quotename(C.name)
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('test') and
               C.name like 'var%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @colsPivot = stuff((select DISTINCT ','+quotename(right((C.name), len(C.name)-5))
         from sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('test') and
               C.name like 'var%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query 
  = ' 
      SELECT var, form,  '+ @colsPivot +'
      FROM
      (
        SELECT distinct substring(field, 1, 4) var, 
          --field,
          right((field), len(field)-5) as col,
          form,
          value
        from 
        (
          SELECT form, '+ @colsUnPivotNull + '
          FROM test
        ) t1
        unpivot 
        (
           value
           for field in (' + @colsUnPivot + ')
        ) unpvt 
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        sum(value)
        for col in ('+ @colsPivot + ')
      ) p
      ORDER BY var, form'

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d99c/43)

This will get the list of columns to unpivot and the pivot at the time of execution.  Then you will not have to hard code the values if you have a lot of columns.